# JSON not getting deserialized automatically in MVC Controller

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am giving an ajax post request to a MVC Controller method, in that request i am passing json data.

i am getting json string in the action method with some additional escape characters(/) so is it something that JSON.stringify method adds some additional characters automatically or due to some wrong configuration i am getting the Json string with these additional characters?

currently i am deserializing this json string with JavaScriptSerializer object into c# object, i am not sure but in MVC 4 it should be deserialized automatically into a c# object ? or is there any way to do it? i have tried Same for wcf serive also but not able to deserialize it automatically i have also added [serializable] attribute in the class but no success. Request you to explain that how it works ?

Thanks, Ankit

Comment: Can you please post your JSON string and your C# code for desalinizing JSON String along with C# model?

Comment: In my case Newtonsoft always work to deserialize JSON string